# Update database linked to DataGrid dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datagrid

I want to put several buttons on my WPF form and update dynamically my DataGrid with the data from a different database for each button, let say, I have 3 databases and 3 buttons, and when you push one button you get the data from 1 different database.

But I want the data on the DataGrid to update back into the database when a change is made on the Grid, so I don't have to program all the "save" stuff.

Right now, the code that I have is this:

```
try
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(
                "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " +
                "Data Source=MaterialDB.mdb");
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM myTable", conn);

            myDataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(myDataSet, "myTable");

            var be = CatalogsGrid.GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty);

            CatalogsGrid.DataContext = myDataSet;
            CatalogsGrid.ItemsSource = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            Binding nbe = new Binding();
            nbe.Source = myDataSet;
            nbe.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            nbe.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            nbe.Path = new PropertyPath("myTable");
            nbe.BindsDirectlyToSource = true;
            CatalogsGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, nbe);


            CatalogsGrid.Items.Refresh();

        }
```

This code loads the data from a database into the grid, but I edit the data and it doesn't update back into the MS Access table.

Oh, it is still not coded but the "myTable" should be a string where I put the name of the different tables I want to show and update from the grid.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can bind in WPF in "two way" mode, in this case the view can change the property it is bound to. Then it's up to you sending it to the database. Sounds like a case for Entity Framework too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataGrid does not save changes automatically, that's up to you (your application) to decide, but it writes back changes to the underlying DataTable.

So as I understand, you want to avoid having a save button and save changes back to the database immediately after they have changed. What you need now is to know when something has changed, and your DataSet can help you with that:

```
myDataSet = new DataSet();
myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables["myTable"];
adapter.Fill(myDataTable);

// Update the DB whenever a row changes
myDataTable.OnRowChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    adapter.Update(myDataTable);
}
```

Comment: Added my answer as a comment, taking this as a starting point the problem was solved. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Create a centralized method that will update the data that is used to bind the data. Create a save button and call the below function. It will save the network traffic for being save the data on every change.

```
public void UpdateDb ( OleDbDataAdapter adap, DataSet ds)
{
    var build= new OleDblCommandBuilder (adap);
    adap.Update (ds);
}
```

Just you need to pass the parameter and it will update the changes made to dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Taking @Bernhard answer as a starting point, had to add the update command and some tweaking, it is now working.

This is the final code:

```
try
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(
                "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " +
                "Data Source=MaterialDB.mdb");
            //conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM myTable", conn);

            myDataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(myDataSet, "myTable");
            DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables["myTable"];

            // Create the UpdateCommand.
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(
                "UPDATE myTable SET Type = @Type, Description = @Description " +
                "WHERE ID = @ID", conn);

            // Add the parameters for the UpdateCommand.
            command.Parameters.Add("@Type", OleDbType.Char, 255, "Type");
            command.Parameters.Add("@Description", OleDbType.Char, 255, "Description");
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer, 5, "ID");
            adapter.UpdateCommand = command;

            // Update the DB whenever a row changes
            myDataTable.RowChanged += (s, f) =>
            {
                adapter.Update(myDataTable);
            };
            var be = CatalogsGrid.GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty);

            CatalogsGrid.DataContext = myDataSet;
            CatalogsGrid.ItemsSource = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            Binding nbe = new Binding();
            nbe.Source = myDataSet;
            nbe.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            nbe.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            nbe.Path = new PropertyPath("myTable");
            nbe.BindsDirectlyToSource = true;
            CatalogsGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, nbe);


            CatalogsGrid.Items.Refresh();

        }
```

Thanks for the help.